# The downloaded files of my program are empty

Tags: javascript, html

Simple put exactly what the title says.

The program should receive a number and then generate as many tables as the given number.

The program is able to generate the tables correctly, but when I try to download them, they are empty.

```js
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;


function criarTabelas() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = ""; // Limpar o conteúdo anterior do container

  var repeticoes = parseInt(document.getElementById("repeticoes").value, 10) || 0; // Valor inserido pelo usuário

  for (var i = 0; i < repeticoes; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "tabelaBingo";
    var tabela = document.createElement("table");
    tabela.innerHTML = "<caption>Tabela de Bingo de Genes " + (i + 1) + "</caption>";

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var resultados;
      if (j === 0) {
        resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes1);
      } else if (j === 1) {
        resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes2);
      } else if (j === 2) {
        resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes3);
      } else if (j === 3) {
        resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes4);
      }

      var tr = document.createElement("tr");
      tabela.appendChild(tr);
      for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        var valor = resultados[k];

        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.textContent = valor;
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    }

    div.appendChild(tabela);
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

var combinacoes = ["UUU", "UUC", "UUA", "UUG", "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "UAU", "UAC", "UAA", "UAG", "UGU", "UGC", "UGA", "UGG", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAU", "CAC", "CAA", "CAG", "CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AUU", "AUC", "AUA", "AUG", "ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAU", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG", "AGU", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG", "GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG", "GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAU", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"];
var combinacoes1 = ["UUU", "UUC", "UUA", "UUG", "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "UAU", "UAC", "UAA", "UAG", "UGU", "UGC", "UGA", "UGG"];
var combinacoes2 = ["CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAU", "CAC", "CAA", "CAG", "CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG"];
var combinacoes3 = ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA", "AUG", "ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAU", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG", "AGU", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG"];
var combinacoes4 = ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG", "GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAU", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"];

function gerarValorAleatorio(valores) {
  var temp = valores.slice();
  var valoresAleatorios = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
    valoresAleatorios.push(temp[indice]);
    temp.splice(indice, 1);
  }
  return valoresAleatorios;
}

function CriaPDF() {
  var tabelaBingo = document.getElementsByClassName("tabelaBingo");

  for (var i = 0; i < tabelaBingo.length; i++) {
    var tabela = tabelaBingo[i];

    var doc = new jsPDF(); // Criar um novo documento PDF

    // Converter a tabela em HTML para uma string de conteúdo
    var htmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(tabela);

    // Definir as opções de estilo para a tabela
    var style = "<style>table { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; } th, td { padding: 5px; }</style>";

    // Concatenar o estilo e o conteúdo da tabela
    var content = style + htmlString;

    // Adicionar o conteúdo convertido ao documento PDF
    doc.html(content);

    // Salvar o PDF com o nome adequado
    doc.save("bingo" + (i + 1) + ".pdf");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  font: 17px Calibri;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tabelas de Bingo</h1>
<label for="repeticoes">Número de Repetições:</label>
<input type="number" id="repeticoes" value="3">
<button onclick="criarTabelas()">Gerar Tabelas</button>
<button onclick="CriaPDF()">Baixar PDF</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.3.1/purify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

This generate the files just right but the moment I download and open then they are empty.
By the way the rumblings in the code are portuguese

I have tried using the librarys suggested and followed the instructions but still there is this single problem of the tables being empty when I download then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code lies in the way you're trying to convert the HTML table into a PDF using jsPDF. The doc.html() method you're using is not a valid method in jsPDF. Instead, you can use the html2canvas library to capture the HTML content as an image and then add that image to the PDF.
I edited the code  and put it in a txt file(link below) and it should work fine now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Tabelas de Bingo</title>

 <style>
     table {
         width: 700px;
         height: 500px;
         font: 17px Calibri;
         margin-bottom: 20px;
     }

     table, th, td {
         border: solid 1px #DDD;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         padding: 2px 3px;
         text-align: center;
     }
 </style>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.3.1/purify.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
 window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

 function criarTabelas() {
     var container = document.getElementById("container");
     container.innerHTML = ""; // Limpar o conteúdo anterior do container

     var repeticoes = parseInt(document.getElementById("repeticoes").value, 10) || 0; // Valor inserido pelo usuário

     for (var i = 0; i < repeticoes; i++) {
         var div = document.createElement("div");
         div.className = "tabelaBingo";
         var tabela = document.createElement("table");
         tabela.innerHTML = "<caption>Tabela de Bingo de Genes " + (i + 1) + "</caption>";

         for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             var resultados;
             if (j === 0) {
                 resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes1);
             } else if (j === 1) {
                 resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes2);
             } else if (j === 2) {
                 resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes3);
             } else if (j === 3) {
                 resultados = gerarValorAleatorio(combinacoes4);
             }

             var tr = document.createElement("tr");
             tabela.appendChild(tr);
             for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                 var valor = resultados[k];

                 var td = document.createElement("td");
                 td.textContent = valor;
                 tr.appendChild(td);
             }
         }

         div.appendChild(tabela);
         container.appendChild(div);
     }
 }

 var combinacoes = ["UUU", "UUC", "UUA", "UUG", "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "UAU", "UAC", "UAA", "UAG", "UGU", "UGC", "UGA", "UGG", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAU", "CAC", "CAA", "CAG", "CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AUU", "AUC", "AUA", "AUG", "ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAU", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG", "AGU", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG", "GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG", "GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAU", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"];
 var combinacoes1 = ["UUU", "UUC", "UUA", "UUG", "UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "UAU", "UAC", "UAA", "UAG", "UGU", "UGC", "UGA", "UGG"];
 var combinacoes2 = ["CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAU", "CAC", "CAA", "CAG", "CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG"];
 var combinacoes3 = ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA", "AUG", "ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAU", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG", "AGU", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG"];
 var combinacoes4 = ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG", "GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAU", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"];

 function gerarValorAleatorio(valores) {
     var temp = valores.slice();
     var valoresAleatorios = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
         valoresAleatorios.push(temp[indice]);
         temp.splice(indice, 1);
     }
     return valoresAleatorios;
 }

 function CriaPDF() {
     var tabelaBingo = document.getElementsByClassName("tabelaBingo");

     var promises = []; // Array to store promises for each table capture

     for (var i = 0; i < tabelaBingo.length; i++) {
         var tabela = tabelaBingo[i];

         var promise = html2canvas(tabela).then(function (canvas) {
             var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

             var doc = new jsPDF(); // Criar um novo documento PDF

             // Define the dimensions of the PDF page according to the captured image
             var imgWidth = 210; // A4 page width in mm
             var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

             // Add the captured image to the PDF
             doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

             // Save the PDF with the appropriate name
             doc.save("bingo" + (i + 1) + ".pdf");
         });

         promises.push(promise);
     }

     // Wait for all promises to resolve
     Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
         console.log("PDFs generated successfully.");
     });
 }
</script>

<h1>Tabelas de Bingo</h1>
<label for="repeticoes">Número de Repetições:</label>
<input type="number" id="repeticoes" value="3">
<button onclick="criarTabelas()">Gerar Tabelas</button>
<button onclick="CriaPDF()">Baixar PDF</button>
<div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```